# How can I create mock `MSALAccount` objects for unit testing in Swift with MSAL framework?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

The company I work for has decided to to their app sign in using MSAL. The process of getting that to work was surprisingly easy. Where I'm having trouble is writing Unit Tests. The majority of the code I need to test is in the closures passed to various `MSALPublicClientApplication` functions related to getting accounts and access tokens. I've created a mock for `MSALPublicClientApplication` and intend to make it pass back whatever objects I need so I can verify that my code actually does what it is supposed to. Simple enough, except I can't instantiate fake or mock `MSALAccount` objects because the makes of the framework have hidden them from external use. The [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Testing-an-app-using-MSAL) suggests "wrap all your authentication logic behind an interface and mock that in your app" which is fine but I don't see how that's going to help solve my problem of not being able to pass my code the objects it needs.

I have tried creating subclasses of `MSALAccount` (with various custom init) only to be told that init has been hidden

I have tried to cast Any and AnyObjects as `MSALAccount` only to be told that the casting won't work and just get a nil.

I've looked at how the framework creates the `MSALAccount` only to find out that they are using code that is not available to users of the framework.